# simple javascript captcha based on strings from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create simple javascript captcha based on strings that I will update in array.

It needs to work this way:

- My array (looks like this: `["black", "red", "blue", "green"]`)
- Select a random string from my array
- Replace the random string that was selected in span with "please write *random string* in the next field"
- Then check `if ($.trim($(".contact-form input#header-answer").val()) === "random string")`

For now I only have created a solution that works with one string and not random strings from my arra, here it is:

```
$(".contact-form form#gform_1").before('<div id="header-question"><span>please write "red" in the next field</span><input id="header-answer" type="text" name=""></div>');

if ($.trim($(".contact-form input#header-answer").val()) === "red") {
  $(".contact-form form#gform_1").submit();
}
else {
  alert('wrong answer try again!');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a captcha... A captcha is made using an image or audio source, to make it impossible for computers and automatic programs to recognize it. So using plain text inside a span (that can be read by any program and cracked in a millisecond) is just useless, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also the server needs to know the "secret". A good browser debugger will suffice

Comment: @Marco Bonelli you are right and i know that! but i need to create simple captcha solution for hebrew strings. most of the bots dont know to work with hebrew. if you know better solution for hebrew strings i will be glad to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I agree with the comments above, and I think the title is incorrect. This is a small snippet of what you are looking for. Again I stress that the above comments are correct in saying this won't act as a secure way of protecting submissions.

```
var a = ["black", "red", "blue", "green"];
var item = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];

$(".contact-form form#gform_1").before('<div id="header-question"><span>please write "' + item + '" in the next field</span></div>');

$(".contact-form form#gform_1").on("submit", function(e) {
    if ($.trim($(".contact-form input#header-answer").val()) === item) {
        //$(".contact-form form#gform_1").submit();
        alert("all good");
    }
    else {
        alert('wrong answer try again!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9wcagLr/

Comment: Thanks @Chris i need to create simple captcha solution for hebrew strings. most of the bots dont know to work with hebrew. if you know better solution for hebrew strings i will be glad to know.

Comment: I am not sure if the hebrew strings would make much of a difference. It boils down to what you are protecting and how important it is to stop bots.

Comment: @user2413244 - Try the Muslim ones!? Anyway most bots are not interested in the language - to them a series of bits

Comment: I am assuming the downvote is my answer doesn't cover the captcha part of the question? If you read the contents of the question, my answer covers all the points being asked (except the misleading title).